# ExpressJs 404 on CSS File

Tags: css, node.js, express, npm

So I am trying to learn how to use expressJS and nodeJS and I am runnning into a problem where the CSS file can't be found (404 error) when I start the server and load the html page. The html page loads fine, but it is not styled when I have the server load it. When I load the page without the server, the page is styled. Here is my code for express and node file:

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express');
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000);
```

The html link for the css is:

```
<link href="public/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The file structure is

- FrontEnd(folder)

  - index.html
  - index.js
  - public(folder)

    - main.css

What am I doing wrong? I have googled and looked at documentation but have not figured out the problem so far.

Comment: Just use [express.static()](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for this. That's what it's for =)

Comment: I am using that. It is in the code 2nd to last line.

Comment: noted, see my answer. If, with that sorted, you still get a 404, *make sure that file exists*, and *make sure the filename is exactly as it exists on disk*. If you have "Main.css" but link to "main.css", those are not the same files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made an incorrect assumption about how the `static` binding works. The following instruction:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

tells express that "any resources requested on `/` that have no explicit routes bound for this app should be resolved through the filesystem; specifically, they should be looked for in the `./public` directory".

So, if someone asks for `/cats.git`, and express doesn't see an explicit route binding for that in your app, it will then check the `./public` dir relative to where it's running, trying to find a file called `cats.gif` and return it if it can find it (or send a 404 if it can't).

As such, what that dir is in your filesystem is irrelevant to the user of your site: they'll simply resolve things against a clean path, so if you have a file `./public/main.css` that you just want to serve as static content, then your CSS link should be:

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then express will see a request for `/main.css`, it'll notice there are no explicit routes defined for it, and will then try to find `main.css` in your static dir(s). It'll find `./public/main.css`, and then simply send that back as response for `/main.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

HTML
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Checked your code, and I even modeled it after yours and tried that, still getting the 404 error.